# What does ?: mean in Java

Tags: java

In the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String echo = (args.length == 1) ?  "Your name is "+args[0]: "Wrong number of arguments!";
    System.out.println(echo);
}
```

It will print your name if you give only one argument, otherwise it will warn you with wrong number of arguments, which is pretty clear, but how does `?:` operator work here?

Comment: It's the "confused face" operator - it means you did not know the term "ternary operator" so were not able to search for it online.

Comment: It's [Elvis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I beg to differ!  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java%20operator - First two hits will give you the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?:` operator is called [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), it is used as follows:

`condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

Your code can be written as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String echo = null;
    if(args.length == 1){
        echo = "Your name is " + args[0];
    }else{
        echo = "Wrong number of arguments!";
    }

    System.out.println(echo);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

```
a ? b : c
```

means: `b` if `a` is true, otherwise `c`

Answer (score 0):

It is sort of like an if clause. The first part of this *ternary operator* is the test statement, and if it evaluates to true it executes the code after ? and if it's not, then it executes after :